# vba excel AdvancedFilter method for a table with dates criteria does not work

Tags: vba, excel, macros

first af all i'm glad to enjoy this nice community, this is my first post so apologize me in advance for any mistake i'll do in the post.

I got a table named *example* generated by importing data from an access file, so the number of rows changes dynamically...I'm trying to apply the `AdvancedFilter` method to this table via VBA.
I've used the first row of the sheet for copying the header of the table and in the second row i set my parameters for filtering, so in the range *A1:D2* i got the criteria. Starting from row 5 i have the table *example*: it starts with a header row and goes on with all the rows of data, all imported from the access file, for example a range *A5:D20*.
If i apply the advanced filter manually (click on the advanced filter button and fill the form) specifying the range of the table *A5:D30* and the range of the criteria *A1:D2* it works fine...but if instead of specifying the range of the data i use the name of the table *example* the result is different, just one row instead of the five (right) rows i expect...why?!?
Now, if the question above is just for curiosity (but i'm sure it's connected with my problem), the main problem is that i'm trying to do the same thing via VBA code. I tried

```
 Worksheets("name").Range("example[#All]").AdvancedFilter _  
 Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("A1:D2"), Unique:=False
```

and

```
Worksheets("name").ListObjects("example").Range.AdvancedFilter _
Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("A1:D2")
```

but both don't work: the filtering action didn't return no lines.

Even if i try

```
Worksheets("name").Range("A5:D30").AdvancedFilter _  
Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("A1:D2"), Unique:=False
```

specifying manually the range (not a solution for my problem because the range changes dynamically, but for test purpose...) the problem persists, the code didn't return no lines.

Note: if i `select` the `range` in the codes above instead of `AdvancedFilter` it the selection is correct: the entire table with the header

The first code is the same automatically written if i start recording a macro, do the filtering manually, and stop recording the macro (code written exactly with the table reference)...the wierd thing is that when i manually do the operation (while recording the macro) it filters correctly, but if i start the macro just recorded...nothing, same as if i run the code written above.

If i open the *formula->names* tab i can find the *example* table but the range specifyed is not starting from row 5 but from 6...it's like the header is not considered, don't know why...but it's automatically generated with the importation of the data so i don't know how to change the range keeping the reference to the imported data...maybe is this the issue?!?

Don't know how to solve the problem, please help me :)

**Edit:**
Two of the criteria i'm using for filter are date criteria, specifically: *date <= xx/yy/zzzz* and *date >= aa/bb/cccc* and the problem it's exactly this...if i try the three codes above filtering with a string criteria, they works, if i use them with the dates criteria, they don't. So i guess the problem depends on how VBA hands the dates data types. Any suggestion?

The cells used for criteria contain this formula ("SE" is the italian version of "IF"):

```
=SE(filtro!F2="";"";">="&filtro!F2)
=SE(filtro!F3="";"";"<="&filtro!F3)
```

i take the criteria from another sheet ("filtro") and if the cell is filled i report the data inserted with <= or >= for the criteria, otherwise the cell remains empty for don't set any condition.

Thanks

Ettore

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem of an issue with using table names in a VBA programmed advanced filter.  So far as the Naming, the behavior you see is normal.  The table name will only refer to the datarange.  If you want to include the header range (which you should), use the `Table1[#All]` format.  Possibly an issue with your data, or how you have set up your criteria.

Comment: I guess that if the problem depends on an issue with the data or criteria, the filter shouldn't work in "manually" mode...But in the same sheet, same table, same data, same criteria if i start an advanced filter by click the button and fill the form with the same ranges i used in the third code i wrote...it works...  Maybe it depends that the table _example_ is generated automatically with the import of the data?

Comment: Sometimes criteria which are dates, or criteria which use local separators, wind up being handled differently in VBA than when done manually.  Since I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided, there is not much more I can do.  If you like, upload a workbook that demonstrates the problem, with sensitive information removed, to some public sharing site, and post a link here.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld you are right! I was trying to filter criteria that are dates...if i try to change the criteria and use a string, works all the three codes i posted...damn me i didn't try. So the problem depends on how the VBA hands the date data. I'll edit the question with this...but the problem still remanis ;)

Comment: And what, exactly, does the criteria look like?  e.g. exactly what is being displayed in the criterion cell?  If `filtro!F2` contains a real date, it should still work.  As I wrote, trying to trobuleshoot without being able to reproduce your problem is quite tedious, and unrewarding.  Can you not devise a workbook that will reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally i fix the issue and whant to share the solution.
As i mentioned in the edit of my question, two criteria of the filter are dates, i found two problems and both are connected with this:

- When i imported the data from other source (access file) and populated the table that i was going to filter i did not set the appropriate format to the fields, i left all as excel decided and this was a problem. The correct way is to set:

  1. The fields in the table (the ones with the data to be filtered) as `date` with a preformatted format (not simple for me because they were stored as text in the access so i must made a *SQL* string for extract data in the correct type and format).
  2. The field where store the condition for the filter as `general` (in my case this field contains the formula mentioned int the edit of my question).
  3. The field where i insert the dates for filtering (the one referenced in the formula) as `date` with the same format as the fields of the table (point 1.).
- The formula mentioned in the edit of my question looks at a cell (where i insert the date) and, if this cell is filled, returns something like *<=data-inserted* or *>=data-inserted* (and this is OK) BUT when nothing is inserted in the cell returns `""`. For a string criteria in the filter this is ok, but for a date criteria is not, this causes the filter to don't find nothing with `""` in the table fields filled with dates. I tryed to use `null` value or other similar *values* but i couldn't find what is *nothing* for a date criteria...so the workaround i used is to return *<=31/12/2100* or *>=01/01/1900* when i don't whant to limit the grater or the lower dates.

Hope this could help someone.
Ettore

Answer (score 0):

Try this below steps. It is working for me.

First we should create a named range (Define Name) (call it is Table),give the range as dynamic using the formula =OFFSET(Sheet1!A5,0,0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$5:$A$100,"<>"),4).

Paste this offset formula while creating the name range - Table.

This formula will changes the range dynamically.

Write VBA code as below

Sub Advanfil()
'
' Advanfilt Macro
'

'
    Range("Table").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Range("A1:D2"), Unique:=False
End Sub

I think the above should ease ur difficulty.

Comment: Sub Advanfil()
    Range("Table").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= Range("A1:D2"), Unique:=False
End Sub

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i can't set the dynamic range as you suggested because may happen that the table have more than 100 rows, and in this case the offset will be wrong. I can expand the range using something like _Sheet1!$A$5:$A$10000_ but doesn't look a good idea because if the table have 10 rows (the dimension changes dynamically) excel will chek 10000 rows...and if my table grows up more than 10000 rows the problem still remains. Anyway i already have a table that holds the precise range, so why don't use it? Anyway, the problem seems to be the way VBA holds the dates data type.

Answer (score 0):

Fill CRITERIA for null or "" cell in date-formatted field with just an equal sign  =

Excel Advanced Filter understands that means BLANK cell